# Custom OpenID provider with Amplify and Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I have a custom OpenID provider setup in cognito and working. I am adding Amplify to my frontend UI but it will not redirect to the sign-in page for the custom OpenID provider, it just redirects to https://undefined/oAuth/... (all the scope, redirect stuff in place of ...). I feel like there is probably some extra config I need to provide to amplify to make sure it redirects to the proper hosted signin (e.g. https://openidsignin.com/oauth/...). Can anyone point me in the right direction. I can find a lot in the docs about using the Facebook/Google as a provider, but not too much for third party OpenID providers.

Comment: This might help you - https://blog.logrocket.com/authentication-react-apps-aws-amplify-cognito/

Comment: AWS docs - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-app-integration.html